# "had looking" vs "was looking"

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple, ellipsis

Quote from *The Anubis Gates*:

"At the far end of the walnut-panelled and carpeted room Darrow, looking no more tired than he **had** last night, was talking to a tall blond man."

Shouldn't this be "..looking no more tired than he **was** last night.."?

Comment: No. There's a "predictably-repeated" verb being "deleted" - ***...looking** no more tired than he had **looked** last night.* We don't know for sure that he really ***was*** tired - only that he ***looked*** tired (about equally tired, on both occasions).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica Is" than he was looking last night" possible? He was looking tired last night.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I see, that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @anouk: The past continuous is syntactically *possible* here (also as the Perfect form *...than he had been looking*), but native speakers would very rarely use it in such contexts. It's not easy for me to explain why continuous isn't really suitable in this *exact* context, whereas it could be fine in something like *That's not what you were saying last night* (as opposed to *...what you **said** last night*, which is also fine). But *in OP's specific case here*, the continuous would normally only occur in (non-mainstream) "Indian English".